# iptables Policy Set to DROP or Create Rules to DROP?

Tags: iptables

[I found this site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-4-block-all-incoming-traffic-but-allow-ssh.html):

In it, the author created default rules:

```
# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

But [in this video @15:24](https://youtu.be/6Ra17Qpj68c?t=914), it's mentioned that you can set a default policy to `DROP` using

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
```

What is the difference between these two methods of creating an initial block all traffic rule set?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. The only difference is whether the rule is created on the command line or in a config file.

The commands are also the same:
[iptables man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables):

```
-P, --policy chain target
```

The config file approach means that setting up rules is consistent, done in the right order, and you can more easily review the whole rule set at a glance.

Comment: Sorry! Stupid question, I didn't realise that -P meant --policy!